# Did Genisys erase T2's plot?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day, terminator-genisys

John was turned by T-5000 and all his men were killed right after Kyle was sent back. Which means he would not be able to send a reprogrammed T800 back later.

Comment: Yes. And created something much much worse- ***Dark fate*** 

Comment: Genisys strongly implies the existence of multiple timelines

Comment: @Valorum Dark Fate outright confirms them by the fact that it completely ignores T3...

Comment: @Moo - lol. It ignores everything after T2. But for stylistic reasons

Comment: @Valorum I actually quite liked it and thought it fitted with T2 and Salvation quite nicely.

Comment: @Moo With T2 and what? :)

Comment: Genisys? What's that??? I thought they only made two Terminator movies: T1 and T2!

Comment: @Valorum But it ripped off T3 stuff.

Comment: It might only erase or alter some aspect’s of T2’s future. Technically, all that is needed in T2’s present is for a reprogrammed T-800 to somehow be sent back in time to protect him, and that movie’s present continues to play out like it did; for example, an even further future reprogrammed T-5000 sent back to stop Genisys’ T-5000. It’s causal loops all the way down.